# Debug model.fit and model.evaluate to see outputs obtained and understand how the calculations are made

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to understand the tensorflow architectures and a way to see how the calculations were made to obtain a result in each epoch at `history` variable in `model.fit()` function:

`history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=16, verbose=0, validation_split=0.3, steps_per_epoch=10)`

and at `model.evaluate()` function, about the final test accuracy and loss obtained:

`loss, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)`

I have tried to debug the functions behind `model.fit` and `model.evaluate` but I realized that there are lots of functions and it makes hard to understand how the calculations are made.

I want to know what should I do to visualize the calculations made in these two functions?

Comment: This post does not contain a question.

Comment: Thank you for the remember @o-90, I inserted now the question, check it out!

Comment: Hi @Victor! You can use [tf.keras.callbacks.BaseLogger](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/BaseLogger) in model.fit operation to log all inside operation then use debug tab from Pycharm to see where the errors are originating.

Comment: Hi @TensorflowSupport, thank you for the feedback! I executed this parameter in the ```model.fit()``` and I got in ```model.fit``` line: ```... ... File "/home/victor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 920, in on_epoch_end
    for k in self.params['metrics']:
KeyError: 'metrics'```. My code was like: ```... from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import BaseLogger ... my_callbacks = [BaseLogger(stateful_metrics=None)] ...  history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_split=0.3, steps_per_epoch=10, callbacks=my_callbacks)```

Comment: @Victor! That might be a bug then. Please report on keras repo. You can use other callbacks like CSVlogger (records the event into csv file) , Tensorboard( visualize operations in graph, profile etc).                                  
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/groom-your-model-using-keras-callbacks-e97b4fa1b21c

Comment: They (```CSVlogger```, ```Tensorboard```) worked here @TensorflowSupport thanks for the help!! Also, I stayed in doubt about how could I see the outputs/calculations made that resulted in each variable: test_accuracy, test_loss, validation_accuracy and validation_loss in each epoch of ```history``` list? I was in this doubt because I would like to justify the obtained results in my thesis and why my architecture resulted in the final ```model.evaluate``` result

Comment: In other words, how each epoch of ```model.fit``` and ```model.evaluate``` functions are calculated, I have tried to debug them to visualize each output but they are very long

Comment: @Victor! You can use verbose = 1 in model.fit or model.evaluate to limit the the logs to 1 line. Just plot the data  on "accuracy" and "loss" from history with respect to epochs to validate over fitting/under fitting/the logs/exploding gradient etc and map it to data from your model.fit logs. [Ref] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/deep_learning_with_keras/deep_learning_with_keras_evaluating_model_performance.htm)